# Окончания в записи числительных (типа 5-ти, 6-х и т.п.)

Tags: орфография, числительные, сокращения

Каким документом регламентируются правила цифровых сокращений числительных?
Когда оставлять в "хвосте" 1 букву, когда 2, когда 3?
Например 6-ых или 6-х?
Смотрел ГОСТ 7.12 – 93 «Библиографическая запись. Сокращение слов на русском языке. Общие требования и правила», не нашел.

Нужно для корректного составления технической документации.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Это не ГОСТ, это просто правила оформления текстов. Сформулированы в нормативных документах, не носящих строго императивного характера, плюс в разного рода изданиях для дизайнеров, верстальщиков, редакторов, типографий и проч.

Нормативно буквенные наращения используются только при **порядковых** числительных.

Правила следующие.

Если форма оканчивается на согласную (включая й), то оставляется одна буква. 
1-й, 2-х, 10-м (первый, [две] вторых, десятым)

Если форма оканчивается на гласную, перед которой идет согласная, то наращение - двубуквенное.
1-го, 2-ми, 10-му (первого, [двумя] вторыми, десятому)

Если форма оканчивается на гласную, перед которой идет другая гласная, то наращение - однобуквенное.
1-е, 2-я, 10-е (первые, вторая, десятое)

В римских цифрах наращения не используют. Кроме того не используют наращения в календарных датах (днях месяца).

Если нужна ссылка на документ, могу поискать.

Но на практике, однако, встречаются более длинные наращения, если иначе затруднено восприятие.

Comment: Спасибо, если не ссылка, то хотя бы название. У меня где-то был «Справочник издателя и автора» А. Мильчина, но старое издание (до Артемия Лебедева)... НАШЕЛ в издании 2009 г.: http://img.artlebedev.ru/everything/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora/Milchin-Numbers.pdf